# Display error message if variable isn't what i expect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, data-annotations

I'm receiving `List<int> percentage` as parameter in *POST controller*.

I'm doing that:

```
var prc = 0;
var prcCount = 0;
foreach (var pr in percentage)
{
    prc += pr;
    prcCount++;
}
if (prc != 100)
    return View();
```

Now I want that instead of *return View();* it display error message that **percentage must be 100**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add message in viewbag

```
if (prc != 100)
    {
      ViewBag.PercentageMessage = "your error message."
      return View();
    }
```

and in view check if ViewBag.PercentageMessage is not null and empty then display message in label.

```
if (ViewBag.PercentageMessage != null)
{
    string message = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.PercentageMessage);
    if(message != "")
    {
      <label>@message</label>
    }
}
```

put this code where you want to display message

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the return type is ActionResult

```
return Content("Percentage must be 100");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string Percentage = "Percentage must be 100";
 if (prc != 100)
   return Json(Percentage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put message in ViewBag, ViewData or model and diplay it with jquery.
Something like this

```
ViewBag.Error = "percentage must be 100";
```

javascript view

```
var ErrorMessage = @ViewBag.Error;
```

jquery

```
if (ErrorMessage.length>0) {   
       $("#divError").show().html(ErrorMessage); 
}
```